# Why does my package in Oracle 11g say my newly created table does not exist?

Tags: oracle11g, schema

I created a table "my_Table" for a project I'm working on. I then need to change the logic in the package to call a select statement on "my_Table" to compare values. When I query "my_Table" in a query window, I get results, but when I try to compile the package it says "Table or view does not exist." I will add that the table is in another schema (schema2) but the package (schema1) also calls tables from schema2 and schema1 has all the necessary privileges, or at least should as I can do all functions to the table. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post all of the relevant SQL scripts used to create the table, package, and grant permissions between the two schemas. There are a number of things that could be at issue and we can't really tell which without seeing exactly what you did.

Comment: Create public synonym  my_table  for schema2.my_table;

Comment: Turns out it was a permissions issue. I'm dumb.